# Update the entity sugar orm

Tags: android, sugarorm

I have this entity on sugar orm:

```
public class PagingSelected extends SugarRecord {
    private String ReadingState,CoutnerState;
    public PagingSelected(){}
    public PagingSelected(String ReadingState,String CounterState){
        this.ReadingState=ReadingState;
        this.CoutnerState=CounterState;
    }
    public void setReadingState(String ReadingState){this.ReadingState=ReadingState;}
    public String getReadingState(){return ReadingState;}

    public void setCoutnerState(String CounterState){this.CoutnerState=CounterState;}
    public String getCoutnerState(){return CoutnerState;}
}
```

and want to update that entity with this code:

```
List<PagingSelected> UpdateEntity= (List<PagingSelected>) PagingSelected.findWithQuery(PagingSelected.class,"Select * from "+NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault("PagingSelected"));
                   UpdateEntity.get(0).setReadingState(ReadingStateCode);
            PagingSelected.update(UpdateEntity);
```

but when run that get this error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: ARRAY_LIST
>   (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE ARRAY_LIST SET SIZE=?

How can i solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your PagingSelected variable is actually an entire list, not a single record. You should get the first record (or whichever you want to manipulate), then change it, then save it back to the db. Trying doing this:

```
PagingSelected currentRecord = UpdateEntity.get(0);
currentRecord.setReadingState(ReadingStateCode);
PagingSelected.update(currentRecord);
```